# Internet Explorer funciona lento con Selenium ejecutando pruebas remotas

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, internet-explorer-11

Comento mi duda por si a alguien le ha sucedido alguna vez:

Actualmente trabajo con pruebas automatizadas de Selenium con RemoteWebdriver, para ello utilizo pieplines en Jenkins que redirigen el trabajo a nodos remotos.
Me encuentro con el problema de que las ejecuciones con IExplorer van demasiado lentas ya que el texto que escribe en los formularios lo escribe letra a letra.

Estas son las soluciones que he probado:

Actualizar a la ultima versión el driver de IE a una versión de 32 bits.

Probé  cambiando estas configuraciones en las capabilities y  en la configuración del driver:

```
 ***DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
 capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);
 driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);***



***InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);***
```

*Esta opción la probé aunque creo que no me serviria por que mis pruebas se lanzan en paralelo y puede tener impacto en la automatización

¿Alguien puede hecharme un cable?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando internet explorer te funciona lento es por la version 64 bit, la 32 bit a mi funciona rapido. Cuando uso la de 64 bit me empieza ejecutar lento las pruebas.

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿en serio seguís probando en IE11 cuando el fin de vida del navegador es literalmente en 30 días? Nosotros dábamos soporte a IE11, pero hace unos meses conseguimos que el cliente lo dejara caer. Buena suerte.

Comment: Respondiendo tu pregunta, algunos clientes(Banca por ejemplo) todavía usan internet explorer por temas de compatibilidad. Lamentablemente uno debe adaptarse a esos requisitos y ejecutar en IE 11. Si fuera por mi lo dejaría de lado es super lento, pero bueno los clientes con app mas modernas usamos chrome o otro navegador mas rapido, saludos